# Cambiar el patron \n por saltos de linea en una cadena

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Tengo el contenido HTML de una pagina *(que convertí a cadena)*. lo extraje con la siguiente linea de codigo

```
url = 'https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandemia_de_enfermedad_por_coronavirus_de_2020_en_Chile'

file = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

contenidoWeb = file.read()
filestr = str(contenidoWeb)
```

El problema que tengo es que normalmente descargo el archivo html directamente y no por URL y eso hace que me quede con saltos de linea, pero al sacarlo por URL me sale todo seguido y los saltos de linea son cambiado por **"\n"**.

Intenté cambiarlo con expresiones regulares pero no logré que el patrón "\n" lo leyera literal. **Este es mi código:**

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
import re


url = 'https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandemia_de_enfermedad_por_coronavirus_de_2020_en_Chile'

file = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

contenidoWeb = file.read()
filestr = str(contenidoWeb)


texto = filestr[0:300]

patron1 = "\n"

cambiar_patron = re.sub(patron1, "", texto)

print(cambiar_patron)
```

**Y éste es el Output en consola:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*En resumen, quiero cambiar todos los **\n** por saltos de linea*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los saltos de linea ya los tienes, es `\n`. El problema es que `read` retorna un objeto `bytes` y para pasarlo a `str` debes decodificar la cadena usando la codificación adecuada.

Lo correcto es usar el `charset` que la propia página debe suministrar mediante los headers para decodificar el contenido de forma adecuada, por mucho que UTF-8 pueda considerarse el estándar es peligroso asumirlo:

```
import urllib.request


url = 'https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandemia_de_enfermedad_por_coronavirus_de_2020_en_Chile'

file = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

contenido_web =  file.read().decode(file.headers.get_content_charset())

texto = contenido_web[0: 300]
print(contenido_web)
```

Otra opción es que usas la biblioteca [`requests`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) que como los propios desarrolladores proclaman es más amigable para humanos:

```
import requests


url = 'https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandemia_de_enfermedad_por_coronavirus_de_2020_en_Chile'

contenido_web = requests.get(URL).text
```

Ya se encarga de la decodificación por ti.

Answer (score 3):

El error ocurre aquí

```
filestr = str(contenidoWeb)
```

`contenidoWeb` es `bytes`. Para transformarlo en `str` usa

```
filestr = contenidoWeb.decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado